# Can't find absoluteLayout function

Tags: nativescript

after pageLoaded, code

```
var page = args.object;
page.bindingContext = vmModule.mainViewModel;
debugger;
var view = page.getViewById("absoluteWrap");
var btn = new button.Button();
debugger;
view.addChild( btn );
 var x = 1;
var count = view.getChildrenCount();
console.log("child count", count, view.setLeft, view.addChild);
//view.setLeft( btn, 100);
setInterval( function(){
    //view.setLeft( btn, x * 10);
    console.log("x==", x, view, btn );      
    x +=1;
},2000);
```

`view.setLeft` is undefined? why?

count value is 1, so the btn is exist.

Answer (score 0):

I find the reason, setLeft is a static method, haha.